# Problems with Language Switcher placement

Tags: 7, theming, i18n-l10n

I have some trouble with the placement of the Language Switcher on a German/English Drupal 7 site. I have read many pages without finding an answer I could work with which may be due to that fact that I messed things up a bit, so please excuse if this seems obvious. And sorry, I am pretty sure that I have misused the concept of the Language Switcher as well as CSS...

What I want: Language Switcher should be in the top of the header on the left as seen in many sites.

What I have: Language Switcher IS in the top of the header on the left BUT it has some shortcomings I would love to get rid off

1. I have placed it absolute which makes it ugly for mobile viewers.
2. It disappears when I am logged in (maybe it is placed too far above?).
3. There is a white box with the ID block-locale-language near the Language Switcher which obviously was part of it but which configuered to death...

Here is what I did in the style.css

```
/*Language Switcher*/

#block-locale-language{
  position: absolute;
  left: 21.2%;
  top: 2.0em;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: none !important; 
}

#block-locale-language ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 210px;
}

#block-locale-language li {
  width: 77px;
    float: left;
}
```

and here is a shot:

[image: the white box with the ID block-locale-language]

Comment: Are you using the developer tools in Firefox or Chrome?  That will help you with the issues as you can edit the CSS live to see where the problems are.  It's quite hard to give a more specific answer.  As for the absolute positioning and mobile you can investigate media queries which allow you to use different styles for screen sizes.

Comment: I do, thanks. And after reading your comment I am pretty sure this is not the right forum for my problems. I thought I might have misused something so obviously that it could be solved by the infos I submitted but I guess you are right: hard to give a specific answer.